# Find the 'Effective Voltage' with only the surface under and above the 't' axis

Tags: voltage

To find the 'Effective Voltage' and the 'Average Voltage' of a voltage over time we have the following functions:

$$V_{eff}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{T}\int_{0}^{T} f(t)^2 \text{d}t}$$
$$V_{av}=\frac{1}{T}\int_{0}^{T} f(t) \text{d}t$$

But in my case it is impossible to find a general function for my voltage so can I use the surfaces? And if I can how can I find the 'Effective Voltage' and the 'Average Voltage'?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why can't you find a general function?

Comment: What is f(t)? Because those formula apply to periodic function

Comment: It is a combination of 4 different functions, it is periodic

Comment: What functions?

Comment: Do them individually to find the RMS of each then add the RMS of each up as per \$\sqrt{A^2+B^2 + ...}\$

Comment: Can I use the surfaces under and above the t axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you might know the *definition* of the definite integral \$\int_{a}^{b} f(x)dx\$ in layman's terms is area under the curve (and above the horizontal axis).

So, yes you could approximate the average value by just manualy calculating the area under the curve. But effective value contains \$f(x)^2dx\$, so you would first have to square the curve to get a new one and then calculate that area.

If the reason you cant solve the integral is that it is too complex you can use one of the online calculators, such as [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) or [Symbolab](https://www.symbolab.com/) to calculate it for you.